# Different Users ID on each sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, column, user

I actually have a site we will call "Team" and one we'll call "Direction"
And a list "Projects" in each of those sites.

I wrote scripts to make save of each sites, looking if there are new entries in each site for "Projects" list, then create a copy it if it doesn't exist on the other site.

So I can have an automatic synchronisation of those two lists.

It's working great except one point, I have a "User or Group" in my list we'll call "In charge of"

When new items upload to one of those sites, it displays me the name of another person.

That's because of Id (LookupID):

Imagine that's my profiles on both sites are:

Team:

```
LookupID; TypeId; LookupValue; 
 _____________________________
12;{c956ab54-16bd-4c18-89d2-996f57282a6f};Gordon Amable
```

Direction:

```
LookupID; TypeId; LookupValue; 
     _____________________________
28;{c956ab54-16bd-4c18-89d2-996f57282a6f};Gordon Amable
```

The difference beetween my two LookupID (16) won't be the same for my mates, so impossible to handle this with a simple calcul.

Any ideas of how I can treat this problem ?

-Should I have an external file for my scripts which will do the conversion automatically ?

But if I do this how can I refresh it like when I add user to sites it automatically harvested and stocked in this list ?

Comment: When you say ``Sites`` you mean Sites in different ``Site-Collections``?

Comment: I think they are both in the same Site-Collections their adresses are like:
Team: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/"
Direction: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/Sites/Mysite Direction/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to fix it was to create a function in my script which basically does:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "\Sites\Team\Users.csv" #Contains: Name;ID
$nbUsers = @($Users).count; 
$objUser =@()

ForEach ($line in $FileIWannaUpload) 
{
    $UserTab = $line.User -split ";#"
    $User = $UserTab[1] #Keeps only "Firstname LASTNAME"
    for ($userIndex = 0; $userIndex -ne $nbUsers; $userIndex++)
    {
    $curItem = @($Users)[$userIndex];
     if ($User -eq $curItem.Name)
     {
      $Replace = $curItem.ID + ";#" + $curItem.Name
      $line.User = $Replace
      $objUser += $line
     }
    }
}
$objUser | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because users get new IDs on each Site Collections.

A user might have ID `12` on one Site Collection but ID `28` on another.

If you have sites located at the `/Sites` managed path, then that is a new Site Collection and not a sub site, thus the user might have another ID.

You can use their name as an identifier, however if you have multiple users with the same `Display Name` then that will be an issue, and you will instead have to rely on the users `Email` address.

Comment: When my script trys to fill the field with a string containing the name (LookupValue = "Gordon Amable") I get an error like I try to update field with unexpected values and nothing is written in the list.

If my script sends the ID (LookupID = "21;#") then I have no errors.

I can't use the Name as identifier because the field simply ignore what is sent after LookupID... 

If I send (21;#"Nelson Mandela") it will still display the "User 21"

Comment: Are you using Javascript or C# to update the lists?

Comment: I use PowerShell scripts with CSOM for Sharepoint 2013